# Parsing error in Protocol Buffer using C++ API

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a test.proto file having the code shown below. I am using code generated by this file in my client server program.

```
message Person {
required string user_name        = 1;
optional int32  favourite_number = 2;
repeated string interests        = 3;
```

}

Client side i have no problem to send data but at the server side i am getting protocol buffer parsing error(in the file:\protobuf\message_lite.cc(line123)) says "cant parse message of type 'person' because its missing required field:user_name"

Though i have checked my client side but couldnt find anything wrong but i might missing something at server side which is not reading string data ?

```
               //Server side code for Protocol Buffers
               Person filldata;
       google::protobuf::uint32 size;
               //here i might need google::protobuf::string stsize; Not sure ?
       google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buffer,filldata.ByteSize());
       CodedInputStream coded_input(&ais);
       coded_input.ReadVarint32(&size);
               //have tried here both coded_input.ReadString and coded_input.ReadRaw
       filldata.ParseFromCodedStream(&coded_input);

       cout<<"Message is "<<filldata.DebugString();
               //still getting same error have no idea what to do exactly to fix it :(
```

Haved [Looked Here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream#CodedInputStream) but still couldnt got it from that explanation, Hope someone can fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buffer,filldata.ByteSize());
> ```

At this point, `filldata` is a newly-initialized message, so `filldata.ByteSize()` is zero.  So, you're telling protobufs to parse an empty array.  Hence, no fields are set, and you get a required fields error.  Messages have variable length, so you need to make sure the exact message size is passed along from the server.

Comment: Thanks it works, now i using instead bytes received by the server side buffer.